# How to set the alignment of the specific header column within tableview in TornadoFX?

Tags: kotlin, tableview, tornadofx

I am using `tableview` within TornadoFX Framework, and I cannot find the right property to set the alignment of the only one header column to the left side.

I managed to set the column content alignment with the `alignment` property set to `Pos.CENTER_LEFT`, but I cannot find the right one to change the alignment of the header cell. Is there any way to do this?

I tried to set the following properties: `alignment`, `textAlignment`, `columnHAlignment` but none of these wasn't work.

Content of `Styles.kt` file:

```
class Styles : Stylesheet() {
    companion object {
        val centerColumn by cssclass()
    }

    init {
        tableCell and centerColumn {
            alignment = Pos.CENTER
        }
    }
}
```

and a part of the content of `MainView.kt` file:

```
...
tableview(people) {
    readonlyColumn("#", Person::id).addClass(Styles.centerColumn)
    readonlyColumn("First name", Person::firstName)
    readonlyColumn("Last name", Person::lastName).remainingWidth()
    readonlyColumn("Age", Person::age).addClass(Styles.centerColumn)

    smartResize()
}
...
```

For example, what would be a solution if I want to set the header column alignment for "First name" to the left side?